# AFNetworking Silently Does Nothing

Tags: ios, ios5, afnetworking

I'm sure I'm dense from being new to iOS programming, but, I am having problems with AFNetworking.  Specifically, when I use it, nothing happens.  I don't get any response from the server, but, I also don't get any errors.  All of the properties end up NULL.

Here is my request:

```
NSMutableDictionary *requestArray = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[requestArray setObject: @"getBio"
                 forKey: @"action"];
[requestArray setObject: @"1"
                 forKey: @"bioID"];

NSError * error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestArray options:0 error:&error];

NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost/LP/JSON/Secure/bio.php" ] ]; 

[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[ request setHTTPBody: [myRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This seems to work as I get my expected result if I simply pass the request into a UIWebView or if I use this:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

In other words, the POST is successful and JSON is returned.

But, none of these do anything (no error, no response):

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"firstName"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"lastName"]);
} failure:nil];
```

Nor does even the bare bones attempt work:

```
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFURLConnectionOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

Obviously, I'm doing something horribly wrong.  But, the silent failures are making this hard to figure out.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Nevermind.. I am dense.

Wasn't creating the NSOperationQueue.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Although, I'm still unclear why the properties aren't getting set.  But, it looks like I at least have data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the request operation object does not automatically kick off the request. Like you pointed out in your edit, it's up to you to either enqueue it into an `NSOperationQueue` or do `[operation start]` manually.

I would recommend that you communicate with your server using `AFHTTPClient`, since that provides a built-in mechanism to correctly set either your query string or HTTP body based on parameters you pass in. See the Gowalla API example client in the sample code, and the method `AFHTTPClient -postPath:parameters:success:failure`.